# Как подключить и использовать Яндекс.Метрику в Meteor+React приложении?

Tags: reactjs, meteor, yandex-metrika-api

Есть приложение, написанное на Метеоре, весь фронтэнд реализован на React, маршрутизация реализована посредством FlowRouter.

Захотел подключить всё это добро к Яндекс.Метрике. И тут появился ряд вопросов. Надеюсь на ваш отклик.

Где нужно создавать и инициализировать счетчик? В документации к Метрике написано, что это нужно выполнить один раз на странице, но никаких конкретных примеров для SPA там не приведено.

Счетчик необходимо поместить на каждую страницу, опять же, в каком месте это лучше делать? Сначала подумал про `componentDidMount() {}`, однако сказано именно по счетчику на *страницу*, а компонентов на странице может быть множество.

Нашел вот такой компонент: https://github.com/narkq/react-yandex-metrika

Но и с ним много неясно.

Где нужно прописывать `ym.init([98765, 4321]);` ? 
Куда помещать `<YM />` ? В каждый компонент?

И где я могу использовать затем методы? К примеру, `ym('hit', '/cart')`. По сути использование этих методов и есть целью всех действий, однако разобраться в верной настройке

Буду благодарен за объяснение или доходчивую статью!

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Прошу подробнее пример применения. ибо не показывает при помещении как описано.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<YM />` - нужно поместить в компонент, который используется *на каждой* странице. В идеале в Footer или Header.

В `componentWillMount();` нужно инициализировать счетчик с помощью ym.init([КОДСЧЕТЧИКА]);

Предварительно подключив следующее:

```
import {Initializer as YM} from 'react-yandex-metrika';
import ym from 'react-yandex-metrika';
```

Далее в любом компоненте где нужно вызывать `ym('reachGoal', 'ЦЕЛЬ');`, также делаешь импорт ym.